# How to use Bash (sed or any other) command to insert at EOF-nth line

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I did search in Stack Overflow, but, I couldn't find a solution. Did try enough.

I have a file containing code like this-

```
...
{
...

 void abc()
 {
  if(condition)
  {
   x=y;
   z=0;
  }
 }
} //EOF
```

I want to insert some lines of code in between `x=y;` and `z=0;`.

This can be done by 2 methods-

1. Searching for the pattern `x=y;` and inserting later
2. Finding no. of lines in file -

   NUMOFLINES = $(wc -l some.txt | awk '{print $1}')
   TOINSERTLINE=NUMOFLINES-5

So, inserting at TOINSERTLINE's value.

More optimal methods are welcome.
Help me fix this.

---

**Concluded Answer from the discussion-**

> sed -i.bak -e '^/x=y;/r file-to-insert' *.xaml

This worked for me!!

Thanks to  **Jonathan Leffler** and  **anubhava**. These were the closest to what I wanted.

Comment: _"I want to insert some lines of code inbetween x=y; & z=0;"_ What kind of content do you want to insert: A fixed string? The content of a file? The result of an other command? An interactive input?

Comment: Rather than piping to awk, you can get what you want from `wc -l` with `wc -l < some.txt`.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Yes, content of a file is what I want to insert. Please suggest a way to do it.

Comment: @WilliamPursell But, doing wc -l won't help me add back my data(from file) back to the same file right? How do I go ahead in doing that?

Comment: Note that you need no spaces around the `=` in the assignment to `NUMOFLINES`, and you can avoid the need for `awk` with input redirection to `wc`, using `NUMOFLINES=$(wc -l < some.txt)`.  Then the calculation should be done using `TOINSERTLINE=$(( $NUMOFLINES - 5 ))` where the absence of spaces around the `=` is mandatory but the spaces inside `$((…))` are all optional (and so is the `$`, but I prefer the clarity of using `$` to indicate references to variables).

Comment: Note that searching and inserting with `sed` is likely to be best unless you have some unmentioned issues (such as the `x=y` line might appear multiple times in the file).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The thing is, the same command appears in around 130 files in the last function. So, I need to manipulate all of them at once. Yes, I did corrections when it comes to spaces. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the problem.  You're on Linux so you're using GNU `sed` so you can use `-i .bak` to make backups of the files, and apply the (same) change to each file.  Of course, if different files need different changes, then you need to do it one file at a time, but otherwise, a simple `find . -type f -name '*special*' -exec sed -i .bak -e '/x=y;/r file-to-insert' {} +` should do the job.  The `find` command determines which files should be edited; it then runs `sed` on conveniently large groups of those files (the `{} +` part), and applies the script to each file in turn.

Comment: If `find` isn't appropriate, you can simply generate a list of the 130 files in another file, then run `sed -i .bak -e '/x=y;/r file-to-insert' $(<list-of-filenames)`.  This is Unix; this stuff is easy because the people who designed Unix designed it to make this stuff easy.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, How do I make a Strictly x=y; pattern match? As I wouldn't want some mx=y; or g x=y; lines to get affected because of the same. So, something like \nx=y;\n would do?

Comment: Use a regex with anchors to start and end of line: `/^  *x=y;$/` or similar. That looks for one or more blanks at the beginning of the line (I wrote two spaces; I don't know whether Markdown will respect that). Or you can insist on 12 or more with `/^ \{12,\}x=y;$/`, or you can allow for trailing spaces, tabs, and other messes if you need to. You can insist on an exact number of spaces if you like; drop the `,` as in `\{12\}`, etc. That's standard `sed` using BREs (basic regular expressions). If you use EREs (extended regular expressions) instead, you have to modify the notation to suit them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Awesome! :) Thanks a lot! I could do what I needed. Perfect solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert a line after 5th line use this `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak $TOINSERTLINE'r data-file' file
```

Here data to insert comes from `data-file`

Comment: This is awesome. It worked. But, what I want is - that number 5 should be from the variable - $TOINSERTLINE . How do I go about in resolving this value in the command? Also, the 'content to insert' comes from a file. Please help me in finishing the unfinished parts.

Comment: Hi, Here is what I am trying. But, on executing the script, the data-file contents was written after every line in the 'file'. Please check the code-

    NOL=$(wc -l looper.xaml | awk '{print $1}')
    echo $NOL
    MINUS=5
    TOINSERTLINE=$((NOL-MINUS))
    echo $TOINSERTLINE
    
    sed -i.bak $TOINSERTLINE'r insert.txt' looper.xaml

Comment: Wasn't able to format the code well in the comment. Here is the link for the same- http://pastebin.com/K312BJNF .

Comment: ok did your final command: `sed -i.bak $TOINSERTLINE'r insert.txt' looper.xaml` work?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
(
    sed '/x=y;/q'
    echo "NUMOFLINES - 5"
    cat
) < file
```

Comment: Are you sure about that?  It looks rather dubious to me.  The `sed` may well read large chunks of the file, and if the `x=y` bit is in the middle of a large chunk, the `cat` can't then read what `sed` already read.  Besides, using three commands where one is sufficient (not to mention a sub-shell too) seems a little OTT.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Somehow just a little while ago I had another answer in which I made a test on it and it works. Yeah that's one to be considered *if* sed does really read large chunks from non-file input. Well actually I just wanted to make a quick reply. It's easy to find a more efficient method if this was really my problem. For trivial matters it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '1; /x=y/{print "foo"}' file

awk -v nl=$(wc -l < file) '1; NR==(nl-5){ print "foo" }' file
```

If those don't do what you want, edit your question to clarify your requirements.